# solana pda clarification

Tags: anchor, pda, typescript

[Youtube solana pda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqINC16QrFM&t=631s)

I've been watching this tutorial for a while trying to build that muscle memory and replicate the code as I understand the concepts, the rust side is not that difficult, maybe when the seeds are explained but overall, I can do that code in about 10 min.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("kYXFfefS45EGgtBwxkdCujNJXUebrKG88okdWc34aDA");

#[program]
pub mod pda_example {
    use super::*;

    //ix create
    pub fn create_ledger(
        ctx: Context<Create>, //<-struct name
        color: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let ledger_account = &mut ctx.accounts.ledger_account;

        ledger_account.color = color;
        ledger_account.balance = 0;

        Ok(())

    }

    //ix modify
    pub fn modify_ledger(
        ctx: Context<Modify>,
        new_balance: u32,
    ) -> Result<()> {

        let ledger_account = &mut ctx.accounts.ledger_account;
        ledger_account.balance = new_balance;
        Ok(())
    }
}

//structs
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(color: String)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = wallet,
        space = 80,
        seeds = [
            wallet.key().as_ref(),
            b"_",
            color.as_ref()
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub ledger_account: Account<'info, Ledger>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub wallet: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Modify<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub ledger_account: Account<'info, Ledger>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub wallet: Signer<'info>,
}

//data account
#[account]
pub struct Ledger {
    color: String,
    balance: u32,
}
```

---

The TS part though has been confusing as soon as start the `createLedgerAccount` function is where I have trouble understanding.
For example in the `await program.methods.createLedger` why is that method called like that? Is that something part of docs?

Then, when adding the `try` and `catch` is something more related to solana/anchor or more into TypeScript?

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { publicKey } from "@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/utils";

import { PdaExample } from "../target/types/pda_example";

//substring of a pubic key
function shortKey(key: anchor.web3.PublicKey) {
  return key.toString().substring(0, 8);
}

describe("pda-example", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  let provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();

  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.PdaExample as anchor.Program<PdaExample>;

  async function generateKeypair() {
    let key = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
      key.publicKey,
      2 * anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );
    //Help understanding setTimeout
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3 * 1000) );
    return key;
  }


  //derive
  //asysnc function with parameters from data account
  async function derivePda(
    color: string,
    pubkey: anchor.web3.PublicKey,
  ) {
    let [pda, _] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      //in rust you have
      //wallet.key, b"_", color
      //question: Does the seeds always have to match between the programs?
      [
        pubkey.toBuffer(),
        Buffer.from("_"),
        Buffer.from(color),
      ],
      program.programId
    );
    return pda;
  }

  //create
  //async functions with parameters from one of the ix in the rust side
  //some of the parameters are what hold the PublicKey and something that holds the Keypair
  //after the parameters, you build a await response for a program method

  async function createLedgerAccount(
    color: string,
    pda: anchor.web3.PublicKey,
    wallet: anchor.web3.Keypair,
  ) {
    //Question: where did .createLedger come from?
    //Question: why pda is not pubkey as in the fn above, both are using .PublicKey
    await program.methods.createLedger(color)
    .accounts({
      ledgerAccount: pda,
      wallet: wallet.publicKey,
    })
    .signers([wallet])
    .rpc();
  }

  //modify

  async function modifyLedger(
    color: string,
    newBalance: number,
    wallet: anchor.web3.Keypair,
  ) {
    //below
    console.log("--------------------------------------------------");
    let data;
    let pda = await derivePda(color, wallet.publicKey);

    console.log(`Checking if account ${shortKey(pda)} exists for color: ${color}...`);
    try {

      data = await program.account.ledger.fetch(pda);
      console.log("It does.");

    } catch (e) {

      console.log("It does NOT. Creating...");
      await createLedgerAccount(color, pda, wallet);
      data = await program.account.ledger.fetch(pda);
    };

    console.log("Success.");
    console.log("Data:")
    console.log(`    Color: ${data.color}   Balance: ${data.balance}`);
    console.log(`Modifying balance of ${data.color} from ${data.balance} to ${newBalance}`);

    await program.methods.modifyLedger(newBalance)
    .accounts({
      ledgerAccount: pda,
      wallet: wallet.publicKey,
    })
    .signers([wallet])
    .rpc();

      data = await program.account.ledger.fetch(pda);
      console.log("New Data:")
      console.log(`    Color: ${data.color}   Balance: ${data.balance}`);
      console.log("Success.");
  }

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    const testKeypair1 = await generateKeypair();
    await modifyLedger("red", 2, testKeypair1);
    await modifyLedger("red", 4, testKeypair1);
    await modifyLedger("blue", 2, testKeypair1);

    const testKeypair2 = await generateKeypair();
    await modifyLedger("red", 3, testKeypair2);
    await modifyLedger("green", 3, testKeypair2);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The function is called `createLedger` because your function is called like that in the program:

```
#[program]
pub mod pda_example {
    use super::*;

    //ix create
    pub fn create_ledger(
        ctx: Context<Create>, //<-struct name
        color: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let ledger_account = &mut ctx.accounts.ledger_account;

        ledger_account.color = color;
        ledger_account.balance = 0;

        Ok(())

    }

    ...
}
```

The `Create` struct describes the transaction context and its dependencies.

I don't understand the second part of your question. The `try`block is put before the modify because you need to create the ledger before attempting to modify it. It's not really specific to Solana or TS

Answer (score 1):

When you `anchor build` a project, it helpfully creates a list of the functions you can call and puts those in `methods`, and also converts them to CamelCase since that is the standard in TS.

SetTimeout stalls the program for a while.

The seeds do have to match in Rust/TS, and a PDA is program unique: it takes the program ID as one of the arguments used to generate the PDA. A PDA is a pubkey with no corresponding secret key, but that's a more complex topic.

Trying to see if a PDA exists by loading it, and creating if it does not exist is a common pattern to "get or init" a pda, that's what's happening with the try/catch.